# react-native-firebase v4.2.0 - unable to find gradle file

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle, react-native-firebase

I'm having the following issue with this version of react-native-firebase.
Can you please guide me into solving this ?

A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-firebase'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-firebase:classpath'.
>   Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0).
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.0/gradle-3.1.0.jar
>   Could not find gradle-core.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.0).

Answer (score 0):

Open in android : **build.gradle** (Project) and look for the following :

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
}
```